# Removing an object from the original array if object value does not exist in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove an object from `arr3` only if the given `username` does not exist in `arr1` and `arr2`.

```
var arr1 = [{ id: 1, username: 'fred'}, 
            { id: 2, username: 'bill'},
            { id: 3, username: 'red'} ];

var arr2 = [{ id: 1, username: 'fred'},
            { id: 2, username: 'ted'},
            { id: 3, username: 'bed'} ];

var arr3 = [{ id: 1, username: 'fred'}, 
            { id: 2, username: 'zed'},
            { id: 3, username: 'zed'} ];


function removeElement(name){
    var found1 = arr1.some(function (element) {
        return element.username == name;  
    });
    var found2 = arr2.some(function (element){
        return element.username == name;
    });

    if (!found1 && !found2){
        for (var i = 0, n = arr3.length; i < n; i++){
            if (arr3[i].username == name){
                arr3.splice(i, 1);    
            }
        }
    }
};


removeElement('zed');

/*
Exception: TypeError: arr3[i] is undefined
removeElement@Scratchpad/6:24:1
@Scratchpad/6:32:1
*/
```

I get this TypeError which I'm assuming is because I change the length of the `arr3` during the for-loop. I could put a `break` statement after the `splice` method but `username` is not unique and all the objects in `arr3` with `username: 'zed'` need to be deleted.

Is there any way to achieve this by directly changing the original array `arr3` without making a separate copy?

Comment: After you splice, you should break, because it fails at arr3[2] due to you splicing on arr3[1], so arr[2] doesn't exist anymore

Comment: If I break, I'd delete { id:2, username: 'zed'} and the loop will end. There is another 'zed' (id:3) which needs to be deleted too.

Comment: "I am trying to remove an object from `arr3`." I guess you meant all objects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Set` collection object.
[Mozilla developer network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) says :

> The Set object lets you store unique values of any type, whether primitive values or object references.

```
var toDeleteItem = new Set(['zed']);
arr3 = arr3.filter(
    // Strings are compared
    obj => !toDeleteItem.has(obj.username)
);
```

See: «[Relation with array objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Relation_with_Array_objects)»

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (!found1 && !found2){
    for (var i = 0, n = arr3.length; i < n; i++){
        if (arr3[i].username == name){
            arr3.splice(i, 1);    
        }
    }
}
```

to

```
if (!found1 && !found2){
    for (var i = arr3.length-1; i >= 0; i--){
        if (arr3[i].username == name){
            arr3.splice(i, 1);    
        }
    }
}
```

When splicing you always want to do it in reverse order, because you shorten the array and every time you splice it's like saying `i = i + 2` because the current element that you removed is now the next element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

is not better, if you find it repeat the index and check the value about if different to `undefined`. I think is most simple and you would not give more complexity to the function

```
if (!found1 && !found2){
        for (var i = 0, n = arr3.length; i < n; i++){
          console.log(i);
          console.log(arr3)
            if ((typeof arr3[i] != 'undefined') && arr3[i].username == name){
                arr3.splice(i, 1);
                i--;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Functional Programming style
Easy to read + understand. Enjoy.
array#filter original array on predicate being if that elements name exists in either of the other 2 arrays remove it.

```js
var arr1 = [{ id: 1, username: 'fred'}, 
            { id: 2, username: 'bill'},
            { id: 3, username: 'red'} ];

var arr2 = [{ id: 1, username: 'fred'},
            { id: 2, username: 'ted'},
            { id: 3, username: 'bed'} ];

var arr3 = [{ id: 1, username: 'fred'}, 
            { id: 2, username: 'zed'},
            { id: 3, username: 'zed'} ];


var filtered = arr1.filter((person) => {
    return !(
        arr2.some((ele) => ele.username === person.username) || 
        arr3.some((ele) => ele.username === person.username)
    )
})


console.log(filtered)
```